# How to adjust 2sxc toolbar and admin menu permissions

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc template on a DNN site (Evoq 08.02.00; 2sxc 9.10.0) that has an edit toolbar with just one button to list content items:

```
<div>@Edit.Toolbar(last, actions: "contentitems")</div>
```

That toolbar appears to my root DNN user, but is not visible to other administrators, let alone users of a custom role, Banner Alerts Editor, that I'd like to access it as well. Is there a setting within 2sxc that will let me adjust these permissions? (I've tried the permissions that can be set within 2sxc content types, but they aren't granular enough to allow access for the additional non-admin role.)

As a workaround, the Admin option within the edit dropdown menu (the pencil icon) is visible to administrators, so those accounts can get to the same screen by navigating to Admin -> Data -> Banner Alert (my custom content type). That's a sufficient workaround for Administrator accounts, but how do I give the other non-admin role access to that Admin option as well?

Comment: have you tried setting the permissions in the module settings to allow your desired role to have edit rights?
 And add something like this to your view template:
```@if(Permissions.UserMayEditContent)
{
       <!-- stuff, like a custom edit toolbar - here an example -->
       <ul class="sc-menu" data-toolbar='{ "action": "new", "contentType": "Gallery Image", "prefill": { "File": "File:@c.Image.FileId" } }'></ul>
}```

Comment: Yes, I tried this without success: ```@if(Permissions.UserMayEditContent) {
                    <ul class="sc-menu" data-toolbar="{ 'action': 'contentitems', 'contentType': 'Banner Alert' }"></ul>
                }```

Comment: There is no additional setting for this - if the user had edit permissions, the toolbar will automatically appear. 

In your case I presume the user doesn't have edit permissions on the module - is that correct? because you could give him the toolbar, but save would fail because of security checks. Or would you just like to give a reduced toolbar for certain users?

Comment: "if the user had edit permissions, the toolbar will automatically appear" – Are these the permissions through the DNN module, or through 2sxc? Within DNN, the custom role has  the "Edit Content" and "Edit Module" permissions checked. Yes, I'd ideally like a reduced toolbar that only gives users in my custom role a "quick link" to the content items list.

Comment: @iJungleBoy Sorry, just realized I didn't tag you, but see my question above and let me know if there's anything you can recommend to get the toolbar working for other users/roles. Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be best to start over in the analysis. a) does the HTML get rendered (you should see a `<ul class="sc-menu">` or something there... b) do you get JS errors?

Comment: @iJungleBoy A. Yes, the ul is there; there's just nothing inside it. B. There is one, "InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement _.Pb @ js:38," but it's coming from Google Maps and I don't think it's impacting this.

Comment: just to be sure - it could be a problem. sometimes a js-error can stop other js from running. could you test on a page without this?

Comment: @iJungleBoy Tested on a page where the error doesn't appear, and switched that page to an entirely different DNN skin to be sure, and in both cases, the `<ul>` appears and is empty.

Comment: I would need a bit more time to figure this out, and/or update 2sxc to change something. so I think we can't handle this on SO, if it's important to you, you should request support https://2sxc.org/en/Contact

Comment: Note that you should use Edit.Enabled and not Permissions.UserMayEditContent. That's a very old interface that has been discontinnued. See also https://docs.2sxc.org/specs/js/commands.html